# cakephp NotFoundException does not display anything

Tags: php, cakephp

1)I wanna throw an error when id is not set or id is wrong.
2)I wanna throw an error when id is set but is not in the database.
Why don't show me anything when i put wrong id? I expected to display the error message.

**ItemController.php**:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Marian39
 * Date: 11/17/2016
 * Time: 8:07 PM
 */

namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException;

class ItemsController extends AppController
{
    public function view($id = null)
    {
        if(!$id)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException(__("id is not set or wrong"));
        }

        $data= $this->Items->findById($id);

        $display = $this->Items->get($id);



 try {
            $display= $this->Items->get($id);
     } 
catch (RecordNotFoundException $e) {
    //no code need
            }


        $this->set('items', $data);

        $this->set('error', $display);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data = $this->Items->find('all', array('order'=>'year'));
        $count = $this->Items->find()->count();
        $info = array('items'=>$data,
                      'count' => $count);
        $this->set($info);
         // $this->set('items', $data);
        // $this->set('count', $count);

        //this->set('color', 'blue');
    }

}
?>
```

**view.ctp from template:**

```
<?php foreach($items as $item): ?>

<div>
    <h2>
        <?php echo h($item['title']);?>
        <?php echo h($item['year']);?>
    </h2>
    <p>
        Length: <?php echo h($item['length']);?>
    </p>
    <div>
        <?php echo h($item['description']);?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

For enhanced exception handling, you should use [get()](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#getting-a-single-entity-by-primary-key) instead of findById().

> If the get operation does not find any results a **Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException** will be raised.
>
> You can either catch this exception yourself, or allow CakePHP to convert it into a 404 error.

In order to check if it's a valid record, you need to mention this on top:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException;

public function view($id = null)
{
    /* Other code*/
    try {
        $data= $this->Items->get($id);
    } catch (RecordNotFoundException $e) {
        // Show appropriate user-friendly message
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I put the code on top of the class. Error:Using $this when not in object context ? 
what changes should be made more concrete? that I did not understand too well..i'm beginner.

Comment: You should put this line: `use Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException;
` before the class starts. And put the try catch block within your `public function index()`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've modify my code and it works only this way. Tell me please if is ok.